# Can't understand this infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf

I have this code to read a file and then print each line but when i run it it keeps printing '1 ; 0 ;  ; 0 ; 0 ; 0' infinitely.
The input file has this in it:

```
1 ; Visitante ; 10 ; 19 ; 2 ; 3
2 ; 1 ; Funcionario ; 8 ; 0 ; 2
3 ; 2 ; Diretor ; 12 ; 19 ; 4
4 ; Visitante ; 8 ; 0 ; 3 ; 2
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void readInput() {
   FILE * fp;
   int id = 0, acompanhantes = 0, entrada = 0, saida = 0, servico = 0;
   char tipo[256] = {};

   if ((fp = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
     printf("Erro a abrir o ficheiro, o programa vai terminar...\n");
     exit(1);
   }

   while ((fscanf(fp,"%d ; %d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d\n", &id, &acompanhantes, tipo, &entrada, &saida, &servico)) != EOF) {
     printf("%d ; %d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d\n", id, acompanhantes, tipo, entrada, saida, servico);
   }

   fclose(fp);

}

int main() {
  readInput();
}
```

Comment: Shall we assume `lerInput` and `readInput` are synonymous ? Regardless, look at your lines. They're not type synonymous, so the lines cannot be universally scanned by the same set of format specifiers. `int`, string, 4x `int`, then 2x `int`, `string`, 3x `int`, scanning fails and input is stalled infinitely failing to convert.

Comment: `fscanf()` returns an int (number of items matched), so it will never match EOF and your loop will never end.

Comment: Your input doesn't match the scanf format.

Comment: @rickdenhaan `EOF` *is* an int and `fscanf` does return `EOF` when it encounters the end of file before reading any input.

Comment: @rickdenhaan how can I solve this then?

Comment: @Jocas test for the number of *successful* arguments processed, not just EOF. `while (fscanf(....) == 6)`

Comment: @WhozCraig I understood the problem but still don’t know  how to solve it

Comment: If you want to copy a file to the standard output, don't assume there's any sort of structure in it. Just read and write it character by character (or line by line or block by block or whatever).

Comment: @sepp2k Just ran a quick test, you're absolutely right. I hang my head in shame...

Comment: @Jocas If you're looking to solve the infinite loop, what I just showed you will do it. If you're looking to somehow successfully process *both* formats of lines, some significant additions are required.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes that's what I'm trying to do because I need to read the file with this specific format for each line.

Comment: @Jocas that "specific format" *doesn't match* some of those lines, so that isn't possible. If you need to handle two *different* formats, it can be done, but would require line-buffering via `fgets`, then multiple potential invokes of `sscanf` rather than `fscanf`, testing for full success along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit [a common gotcha of the `scanf` functions](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). If they fail to scan they'll just keep trying to rescan the same input over and over again.

In your case the first line of your file does not match your format.

```
1 ; Visitante ; 10 ; 19 ; 2 ; 3
"%d ; %d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d\n"
```

So `fscanf` matches the first column, and fails on the second. It returns the number of items matched: 1. That isn't `EOF` so it repeats on the same line over and over again.

Normally you'd fix this by checking `fscanf` returns the total number of items to be scanned. `fscanf( ... ) >= 6` But this doesn't solve that you have a file with different fields in it.

First, we can solve a lot of potential issues by separating reading the line and parsing the line. Use `fgets` + [`sscanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) instead of trying to do them at the same time with `fscanf`. Not only does this avoid infinite looping, but it gives us more room to play with the parsing.

Then we can read the line once, and try to parse it with the various formats until one works.

```
char line[4096];
while (fgets( line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    if(
        ( sscanf(line,"%d ; %d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d\n", &id, &acompanhantes, tipo, &entrada, &saida, &servico) >= 6 ) ||
        ( sscanf(line,"%d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %d\n", &id, tipo, &acompanhantes, &entrada, &saida, &servico) >= 6 )
    ) {
        printf("%d ; %d ; %s ; %d ; %d ; %d\n", id, acompanhantes, tipo, entrada, saida, servico);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse %s.\n", line);
    }
}
```